# How to share an image directly using Whats App Direct in Android

Tags: android-intent, whatsapp

**I have a code of directly Sharing an Image to What's app numbers that are not saved in contacts**

Now How can I send an image also with the existing code

```
private fun shareOnWhatsapp() {
        val senderNumber = sharedPrefs.getString("senderNumber", "") ?: ""

        if (senderNumber.isNotBlank()) {
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$senderNumber&text=$consignmentNo")))
            return
        }
    }
```

**Note: I had tried to change the ACTION_VIEW TO ACTION_SEND any other suggested solution?**